# Splitting multi dimension arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have an array of data from from my database, it looks like this

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 40
        [market] => EUR/USD
        [date] => 2012-02-29 12:20:34
        [points] => 42
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 41
        [market] => EUR/USD
        [date] => 2012-02-29 13:23:03
        [points] => 11
    )
```

and it goes on like this till the end of the database query which is something like 200 records. The database has information for a whole month with multiple records for the same day.

Anyway i want to be able to go through the array and take out all the information for a single day (By the why the information coming from the database is already sorted DESC).

How would i do this? I've looked at "array_splice" and "array_file" but i'm struggling to put them into this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you fetch them from sql?

Comment: @WaqarAlamgir DO you mean query the database for every day? that would mean doing 20+ queries on the database at once, thought that might be a bit to much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like

```
$output = array();
foreach ($input as $row) {
    $date = substr($row['date'], 0, 10);
    if(!isset($output[$date])) {
        $output[$date] = array();
    }
    $output[$date][] = $row;
}
print_r($output);
```

Comment: Could you should me how i'd display the values? i want to get the date and points out of the array for each record for a single day. I'm used to getting the data from my original day but I'm not sure how to access the data now.

Comment: foreach($output as $date => $rows)
foreach($rows as $row)
print_r($row)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$by_day = array();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $by_day[date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['date']))][] = $row;
}
```

Comment: You're right. I thought, I experienced that a while ago - just tested it, no error! I upvote you :)